# Particular div to refresh onsumbit using ajax or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want a particular div on a page that contains database field to refresh itself to bring out the currenty entry onsubmit of a form. the div that contains the record is called #new_entry

```
 <div id="new_entry"></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form3").on('submit',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../calls/insert_call_love.asp",
            data: data
            }).success(function() {

     $("#feedback").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>Your have loved this photo </div>");

                setTimeout(function() { 
                    $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                        $(".messages").remove();
                    }); 
                }, 1000);

                $("input[type=text]").val("");

            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

this is what i'm posting to the insert_call_love.asp

```
<form action="<%=MM_editAction%>" method="post" name="form3" id="form2">
          <input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" size="50" />
          <input name="imageField3" type="image" id="imageField3" src="../imgs/buttons/comment.png" align="bottom" />
          <input name="wardrobe" type="hidden" id="wardrobe" value="1" />
          <input name="comme" type="hidden" id="comme" value="2" />
          <input name="comfn" type="hidden" id="comfn" value="3" />
          <input name="photo_id" type="hidden" id="photo_id" value="4" />
          <input name="ctype" type="hidden" id="ctype" value="picture" />
          <input name="resp_email" type="hidden" id="resp_email" value="5" />
          <input name="MM_insert" type="hidden" id="MM_insert" value="form2" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Please provide some more details and what you want exactly? What you are returning from server in response? What you want to display?

Comment: U have already done that using ajAx

Comment: To change the value of a div use .html() to replace the content inside. $('#new_entry').html(value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have to add a variable to `success(function())` function

```
success(function(msg)
```

**`"msg"`**will contain data which you want to return from below url:-

```
url: "../calls/insert_call_love.asp",
```

then you can assign this data to any `div`

```
}).success(function(msg) {
   $('#new_entry').html(msg);
}
```

**Note:** variable `"msg"` will contain all the data which you have printed on the page `"insert_call_love.asp"`

Comment: use alert(msg) in "success" and check what it returns, if its not empty then it should work, otherwise "insert_call_love.asp" this file is returning nothing

Answer (score 0):

Well depending on what you are doing on the server side with this post...You would need to query the DB and retrieve the latest item, and send it back/echo it out as JSON.

So in pseudocode steps...

```
     Process posted variables...
       Query DB for latest entry..
           Echo out as JSON...
```

Then do something like ...

```
.success(function(data) {
    $('#new_entry').html(data);
```

Comment: please can you phrase your answer into my code, cos i'm new to jquery and ajax

Comment: Weell I need more info than your front end.  I need to see what your'e sending back fro the server.  Like I said.  Otherwise I have no idea.  But if you simply query the DB server side after the post, and echo as JSON.  Then all you have yo change on your client side is the two liines that I show

Comment: I need to see whats going on in calls/insert_call_love.asp to be able to tell you how to echo out the latest row from the DB as JSON, so that my above code will work.  Although, I sont know ASP, so someone else might have to help with that

Comment: i've editted the question and place in the html of what i'm sending to insert_call_love.asp

Comment: That only shows the form. we'd need to see the page that is processing the form.  Because thats where you will query the DB , get the most recent entry, and send it back as a JSON mesage, so  it can be send to the DIV via the success:function(data){}